# Gensim - Trying to load a text file in gensim

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, gensim

Trying to load up a file in gensim with this line of code :

```
model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(r"C:/Users/dan/txt_sentoken/pos/cv000_29590.tx", binary=False)
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:'films'
```

Help how do I solve this error ?

Answer (score 1):

Each corpus need to start with a line containing the vocab size and the vector size in that order.

Answer (score 0):

The first line must contain the number of words and the dimension of your vectors. You can find the example of word2vec and glove format here: [This](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/scripts/glove2word2vec.html).

```
9 4
word1 0.123 0.134 0.532 0.152
word2 0.934 0.412 0.532 0.159
...
```